# Chebyshev differential equation solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

We have

$\frac{d}{dx}((1-x^2)^\frac{1}{2}\frac{dy}{dx}) + n^2(1-x^2)^\frac{1}{2}y=0$ for integer $n\geq0$,

and the question says to substitute $x=\cos z$, which leads to

$y''(z) + n^2y(z)=0$,

and then solving gives

$y(x) = A\cos(n\arccos(x)) + B\sin(n\arccos(x))$.

The question then says to show solutions $T_n(x)$ of the equation that are polynomials of degree $n$ and satisfy $T_n(1)=1$ are given by

$T_n(x)=\cos(n\arccos(x))$.

How do I get to this? If I use my answer from the first part,

$y(x) = A\cos(n\arccos(x)) + B\sin(n\arccos(x))$,

then all that $T_n(1)=1$ tells me is that $A=1$ since

$\sin(n\arccos(1))=0$,

and then

$T_n(x) = \cos(n\arccos(x)) + B\sin(n\arccos(x))$

is a polynomial of degree $n$ so seems to work for any $B$?

Comment: To show it's a polynomial of degree n, use $\cos{(n y)}=\Re \left\{\cos{n y} + i \sin{n y}\right\}=\Re \left\{(\cos{y} + i \sin{y})^n\right\}$, then rewrite this a bit and use $y=\arccos x$.

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in the equation  $\frac{d}{dx}((1-x^2)^\frac{1}{2}\frac{dy}{dx}) + n^2(1-x^2)^\frac{1}{2}y=0$ because the solutions are in contradiction with what is expected latter: The solutions involves the Mathieu's functions.

Certainely, the equation is :
$$\frac{d}{dx}((1-x^2)^\frac{1}{2}\frac{dy}{dx}) + n^2 \frac{1}{(1-x^2)^\frac{1}{2}}y=0$$

[image]